# Disabling textarea and input at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I disable a textarea like in this code snippet:

```js
function toggleDisabled(_checked,id) {
  document.getElementById(id).readOnly = !_checked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="no" value="1" onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked,'new_order')">
<textarea name="noa" id="new_order">FOOO</textarea>
<input type="text"  name="noo" id="new_order">
```

Now I want input text to get disabled when I check the checkbox. So that both textarea and input:text will be disabled.

I tried to add the id that I used as ID for textarea but input:text and textarea are conflicted since readOnly is only for textarea.

So that I need a way tp say if textarea disable like this... , if input disable like this ...

Comment: One problem you have here is that the `id` attribute is required to be unique. You should not have an `input` and a `textarea` with the same id.

Comment: Small detail, but if you want the textarea to be disabled when the checkbox is checked, it shouldn't be `= !_checked` but `= _checked`

Answer (score 1):

1. `id` must be unique! Never use same id to more than one element.
2. the code below selects all elements that have the class `new_order` and then iterate through then disabling or enabling then. Take a look

```js
function toggleDisabled(self) {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('new_order');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].disabled = self.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="no" value="1" onchange="toggleDisabled(this)">
<textarea name="noa" class="new_order">FOOO</textarea>
<input type="text" name="noo" class="new_order">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises when you use an id multiple times... ID's are supposed to be unique.  If you use classes it should work:

```js
function toggleDisabled(_checked, selector) {
 document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((el) => {
   el.readOnly = _checked;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="no" value="1" onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked,'.new_order')">
<textarea name="noa" class="new_order">FOOO</textarea>
<input type="text"  name="noo" class="new_order">
```

Comment: your snippet doesn't work as expected, I mean, when checked then the inputs become enabled, need to be the contrary

Comment: @CalvinNunes just fixed it (I accidentally copied your code a bit too much)

Comment: Rather than using selector ( class ), can you make it work with id ? . @LeinardoSmtih

Comment: @SNaRe you could I suppose change the selector to be instead of '.new_order' to be '#new_order1, #new_order2'  But you cannot select multiple elements using an ID like the op was doing.

Comment: I tried this for multiple IDs and it didn't work.I have this in a lot of duplicate pages. So that I have to use multiple elements to save time. Isn't it possible if I could do something like textarea#neworder in the function so that if id belongs to textarea do this, if input text do this.

Comment: @SNaRe you can use id's but only to select one element.  That is just the nature of ID's.  If you need to select multiple elements you can either name them different ID's or you can use a class.